# Unable to build App with IdeEventQueue Error

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio-3.5.3

I'm trying to rebuild an app that had successfully built with no error before...
I'm using:

```
Android Studio 3.5.3 <br/>
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548, built on November 15, 2019<br/>
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64<br/>
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o<br/>
Windows 10 10.0
```

Now I have this error...

```
EventQueue.isDispatchThread()=false Toolkit.getEventQueue()=com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue@677ad257
Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 7,4,Idea Thread Group] 81107438
SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 3.5#AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548 Studio, eap:false, os:Windows 10 10.0, java-version:JetBrains s.r.o 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03,6,Idea Thread Group] 465932904
```

I have checked through my gradle files and doesn't seem to me like anythings wrong

Here's my **build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.platinum.innovations.paidpad"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
}
```

**build.gradle (Module)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
rootProject.name='PaidPad'
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

After much trials... I simply invalidated the cache and restart... With internet connectivity.